# MySQL inline (SELECT ... WHERE) not working on 5.6

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run a query like the following:

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT columnA WHERE columnB)) AS filtered_list FROM ...`

This works on MySQL 5.7 but not 5.6. I'm wondering if there's a workaround or if this is simply unsupported before 5.7. I can't find anything in the [update documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-additions) that would explain the change in syntax.

Here's a simpler version for testing:

`SELECT 1 AS a, (SELECT 1) AS b, (SELECT 1 WHERE 1) AS c`

This works fine on MySQL v5.7, but on v5.6 the last column will throw a syntax error. Does anyone know a way to make this work?

Comment: `SELECT 1 WHERE 1` is not valid in MySQL 5.6, because there is no `FROM` clause. The workaround is to include `dual` as a dummy table when there aren't any tables referenced, e.g. `SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE 1`.  As far as getting the original syntax to execute in MySQL 5.6, I don't think that's possible. (I'm surprised that MySQL 5.7 allows that syntax.)

Comment: New versions of programs generally try to ensure that anything that worked in the old version still works (exceptions are noted in the release notes). They can't do anything to make the old version understand everything that works in the newer version.

Comment: @spencer7593, that solved it. I assumed the `FROM` was the issue, but didn't know about `DUAL`. Thanks. If you put as answer I'll mark correct.